# How to extract profile picture of given gmail Id?

Tags: google-people-api

Wanted to get profile picture of gmail account not in logged in contact.

Please help to provide api details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to your People's API `poeple.get` endpoint.
See this: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get

Here's a small example in AppsScript:

```
  var personId = "people/c270671618018064333";
  var person = People.People.get(personId, { 
    "personFields": "names,photos"
  });
  Logger.log("person: " + person);
```

will print something like:

```
{
  "etag": "%EgYBAj0DNy4aBAECBQciDGtsWVp4WFRqYkaCQ==",
  "resourceName": "people/c270671618018064333",
  "photos": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "source": {
          "id": "...",
          "type": "CONTACT"
        }
      },
      "url": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-byp3pR_1gu8/.../photo.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "names": [
    {
        ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you're photo url is at `person.photos[0].url`

Comment: Thanks. How to obtain personId of unknown Gmail ID.